# cannot export data from CPT UI (books)

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, custom-taxonomy, export

I am working on migrating a website that was built with CPT UI & 'Advanced Custom Fields.'

The intent is a library of translated books, and the custom taxonomy from these tools permitted the books to be created with enough fields for classification (ISBN + OCLC; Author + Translator; Original Publish Date + Translated Publish Date; etc.).

Problem is, I can't get that data to export. Other custom things exist in the WP export tool, but not the Books one (or Links, but there aren't 300 of those to move around).

Long question short ... where else can I check for those Books to export with WP tools?

Comment: Both of the plugins has their own export tool. Check for the Tools submenu in both Plugin Admin menu.

Comment: Thank you Abhik, unfortunately neither of those export the book data.
I was able to use a different data export plugin to get it, to CSV at least. -_- 
Seems I will be rebuilding the site with some better tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in CPT UI to enable export for the post type:

[image: Can Export CPT UI]

After setting this value on True you can export the posts including meta_fields (+ACF) on **Tools > Export**. For CPT UI this value is by default false.

The `can_export` value is passed through to the register_post_type() function.

See `can_export` on: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/